# Convert i/q data to power measurement (e.g. db)

Tags: signal-processing

I have raw i/q data from an rtl-sdr.  I want to do stuff with signals and different frequencies, but only if they exceed a threshold power.  Software like gqrx, sdr#, etc. take the same data from rtl-sdr sticks and express the energy at a given frequency as a dB measurement (dbFS, or whatever.)  How can I do the same thing?

Comment: I don't know what an rtl-sdr is. I am guessing sdr is software-defined radio. But the instantaneous magnitude of a complex signal is the vector sum of its in-phase and quadrature components. So if you need the instantaneous signal magnitude, you can calculate it that way. (square root of sum of I squared and q squared). In order to single out a particular frequency, you will have to use Fourier methods, which can be pretty complex. Although if you just do an FFT on your data, and display the spectrum, that is pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you take the I & Q signals and perform a Fast Fourier Transform (FFT). This gives you a spectrum (or waterfall) which shows you the relative strength of signals.

Don't forget, dB is a logarithmic scale. You will need to change the magnitude (y) scale after the FFT, but before displaying it on screen. Then you will need a method of selecting a signal on the display, to be further processed and turned into audio.

If this sounds a bit too complex, you can always try reading through the github [source code](https://github.com/csete/gqrx) for gqrx. You can check out the SDRSharp source code [here](https://code.google.com/p/sdrsharp/source/checkout).

Comment: Will doing sqrt(i^2+q^2) provide information about the power level of the signal at the frequency where I'm taking samples from?

Comment: @horsehair, this is a complex area full of technical issues, and you are using language that is not as precise as I would like. When you say "frequency where I am taking samples from" does that mean that the signal is already known to be primarily a single frequency? Or are you asking whether it will provide information about the power level of the actual sample frequency? If the signal is already known to be dominated by a single frequency, then the problem is much easier. You can use an RMS calculation. Include enough samples to span several periods. If the data contain multiple signals...

Comment: ... at different frequencies, you will need to somehow separate out the signal of interest. FFT is not the only way, but it is probably the easiest way to implement, assuming you can use an FFT library. Due to Nyquist, a signal at the sampling frequency will basically be lost (it comes through as DC). Again, a complex area when considered fully.

Comment: @mkeith - When a SDR is tuned to a frequency, the i/q data that comes from the radio represents readings at that particular frequency, correct?  So can I use something like sqrt(i^2+q^2) without worrying about fft?

Comment: @horsehair, my background in this stuff is in radar, and I only did very simple signal processing stuff. But if you are tuned to a narrow band frequency, and if there is only one signal of interest in the band, then yes, you can use that formula. Here is what I think you need to do: step 1, calculate magnitude of each i/q pair per formula; step 2, calculate the RMS value of the signal. You have to use enough data points in the RMS calculation for it to be valid. You have to include enough points so that you span several periods of the signal of interest.

Comment: As Alan said, the i/q pairs are on a linear scale of some sort. So to get dB, you need to convert to a log scale. Do this last (after RMS calculation). Since your data at some point probably represent voltage, you can use 20 * log (RMS magnitude) to convert to dB. This is dB relative to an arbitrary or unknown reference. To get dBm, you would need to understand the gain of the system from end-to-end, or calibrate by using a known power source or something like that. If there is anything important at stake here, seek expert help. If you are on a learning journey, keep at it!

Comment: As a simplification, the 20 in the dB formula cancels the square root in the RMS forumla, so you can just average the sum of I^2 and Q^2 from several samples to get power. Then take 10*log(P_avg) to convert to decibels.